# Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element. When attempting to load first component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-dom

I am using a ReactJS tutorial from [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G40iHC-h0c0) on setting up my first component.

Now the code in my files looks exacly the same:

```js
//index.js
import React from "react";
import {
  render
} from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1> Hello </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render( <App/> , window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>ReactJS Basics</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, this is my **webpack.config.js** file:

```
var path = require('path');

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + '/app/index.js',
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + '/app',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/app/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

And **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "reactjs-basics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Lol",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && xcopy \"src/index.html\" \"dist/\" /F /Y && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && xcopy \"src/index.html\" \"dist/\" /F /Y"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "reactjs"
  ],
  "author": "Alan",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

I am running the server with the `npm start` command from the package.json

---

But for some unknown reason, when rendering the app I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM
>   element.

I really have no idea how to fix this issue, all the other similar problems here contain having the `script` tags above the `hook div`, which is not the real case here.

Has anyone here had similar problems to this?
Any help would be amazing

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('app')` instead of `window.document.getElementById('app')`.

Comment: @Andy thanks for the suggestion, but same result

Comment: @Andy That shouldn't make a difference. `window.document` and `document` are the same thing though the latter is more succinct.

Comment: Yeah, I know :) but everything else looks correct it might have been a (very unlikely) bug (I only use the succinct version).

Comment: @aln447, try... `document.body` - see what happens then. Also, how are you building this? Are you using `create-react-app` or another similar boilerplate, or are you writing your own from scratch?

Comment: @Andy `document.body` didn't work as well unfortunatelly. I am using a custom webpack script. Please see the updated question

Comment: @aln447, I just copied everything here and got it to work straight away...

Comment: This seems to be a bug of some sorts. I have got over it by using `create-react-app` but the problem is still unsolved